# Cache query cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I have a site developed in cakephp. I want to cache a query. I have read the documentation and I have in my `bootstrap.php` this:

```
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));

Cache::config('short', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 hours',
    'path' => CACHE,
    'prefix' => 'cake_short_'
));

// long
Cache::config('long', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 week',
    'probability' => 100,
    'path' => CACHE . 'long' . DS,
));
```

My controller to store the query is this:

```
public function test_view () {
    $product_general = Cache::read('product_general_query', 'longterm');
        if (!$product_general) {
            echo("test");
            $product_general = $this->Product->query('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products');
            Cache::write('product_general_query', $product_general, 'longterm');
        }

        $this->set('product_general', $product_general);
}
```

Everytime that I enter into the page it print me "test" because doesn't find the query into the cache. Where is the problem? Have I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your cache configuration `'long'` inside your core.php but using configuration `'longterm'` inside your action

Also, If you have enabled debugging (e.g. debug set to 1 or 2 in your core.conf), the cache duration may be set to 10 seconds automatically. Not sure if this will apply to your own cache definitions as well though

Comment: I have change longterm to long and now works..! But I don't know about 10 seconds, I can configure the time into my bootstrap right?

Comment: Yes, but I think the debug only affects the default cake cache configuration, so your own configurations will probably be ok. I was thinking out loud as to why the cache may not be working.

Comment: I have test now, I have wait 2 minutes but echo doesn't print, my cache now is long  ore than 2 minutes, I continue to test how much time is store, thanks

Comment: As a further improvement to your code, I would suggest to move the caching logic to your model ('fat models'), e.g. Create a method inside your model (`getDistinctProducts()`), this will keep your code cleaner

Comment: uhm interesting, I can try It, but I don't know because this quert is used in many part of my site with different parameters and complicated code, I have think to move that into my own component

Comment: Even more reason to move it to your model (or a behaviour), e.g. create a `queryCached($sql)` method for custom SQL statements and use MD5($sql) as the cache-key. You should try to prevent using plain SQL statements though, and use regular CakePHP 'find()' statements. Those can be cached as well, e.g. Add some logic to the beforeFind() callback. In any case 'fat' models are good practice, try to keep as much logic for retrieving data inside the models, this will keep your code cleaner and easier to maintain in case of modification to your model/database